# Trying to print an array out of a cookie

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I am trying to print my Array out of a cookie. However when I run the script I get this error. 
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:/Xampp/etc..
Value: array

This is my code:

```
<?php


$NewCookie = "NewCookie";
$NewCookieArray = array("CookieValueOne <br>", "CookieValueTwo<br>", "CookieValueThree<br>");
setcookie($NewCookie, json_encode($NewCookieArray),time() + (3600*24));
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php


if (!isset($_COOKIE[$NewCookie]))
{
echo "Cookie named '" . $NewCookie . "' is not set!<br>";
}
Else
{
    echo "Cookie named '" . $NewCookie . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $NewCookieArray = json_decode($_COOKIE[$NewCookie]);
}
```

?>

Comment: Exactly what it says. You have an array, you can't just `echo` it. Try `print_r` or `var_dump` for testing, and some kind of `foreach` loop or similar for production.

Comment: `json_decode()` takes a JSON String and makes it into a PHP array or a PHP object. You cannot `echo $anArray` or `echo $anObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
  echo "Value is: " . $NewCookieArray = json_decode($_COOKIE[$NewCookie]);
```

With this one:

```
  echo "Value is: <pre>" . print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE[$NewCookie],1)) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Yep this worked! The problem is that the result has to look like this:

CookieValueOne  

CookieValueTwo  

CookieValueThree  

And not like:

Cookie named 'NewCookie' is set!
Array ( [0] => CookieValueOne 
[1] => CookieValueTwo
[2] => CookieValueThree
) Value is:
1

Still happy I got it printed though!